# What is the basis for a parsec in the Star Wars Universe?

Tags: star-wars

From [Wikipedia Article on Parsec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec):

> The parsec (symbol: pc) is a unit of length used to measure the large distances to astronomical objects outside the Solar System. A parsec is obtained by the use of parallax and trigonometry, and is defined as the distance at which one **astronomical unit** subtends an angle of one arcsecond, i.e. 1/3600th of a degree.

From [Wikipedia Article on Astronomical Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit):

> The astronomical unit (symbol: au, ua, or AU) is a unit of length, roughly the distance from Earth to the Sun and equal to about 150 million kilometres (93 million miles). However, that distance varies as Earth orbits the Sun, from a maximum (aphelion) to a minimum (perihelion) and back again once a year. **Originally conceived as the average of Earth's aphelion and perihelion**, since 2012 it has been defined as exactly 1.495978707×10<sup>11</sup> m. The astronomical unit is used primarily for measuring distances within the Solar System or around other stars. It is also a fundamental component in the definition of another unit of astronomical length, the parsec.

So, as *Star Wars* happens in a galaxy far far away, why are they using the average distance between Earth and the Sun as a distance of measure and how do they know it?

Comment: How do they know what a year is?  How do they know what an hour is, or a day?  How are they (mostly) speaking English?  This is the sort of question that's pretty commonly answered by, "You have to suspend disbelief here."  Or you can assume that whatever translates their alien languages into English also handles time/distance/etc terms.

Comment: @Jeff If only every SF/F writer was like Tolkien and wrote hefty appendices detailing the *original* languages, calendrical systems, etc. used by their characters before the "translation" of the story.

Comment: Pretty sure you could argue they don't know what a parsec is.

Comment: "*A parsec is a real-world unit of astronomical distance equivalent to about 19 trillion miles (That's about 19,000,000,000,000 miles!) so Han's boast is about his ship's ability to withstand shorter, more dangerous routes through hyperspace, rather than its speed."* - [Star Wars Made Easy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Made_Easy:_A_Beginner%27s_Guide_to_a_Galaxy_Far,_Far_Away)

Comment: Note that none of the canon sources confirm that a Star Wars parsec is identical to an Earth parsec. The only sources that do that are Legends sources.

Comment: @Valorum Yeah... I dunno, sounds just a little post hoc :) I kinda feel like, if that was the intent, there are far better ways to write that line than to expect the viewer to piece this together.

Comment: How has no answer yet mentioned that the weird part in the definition of "parsec" is _not_ the "parallax" part! The weird part is the notion of dividing the unit circle ([τ](https://tauday.com/tau-manifesto) radians) into 360 little parts, and then subdividing it further into 1296000 teeny tiny little parts called "seconds." Blame the Babylonians. Who lived on... wait for it... _Earth._

Comment: @Valorum: I'm a 100kWh sure they used the wrong unit and had to come up with an explanation once they realized their mistake. But okay, it would be like saying that some machine is able to reach New-York from Paris in only 5670km (by digging a tunnel) instead of the usual 5840 km (flying).

Comment: @EricDuminil I have read, though I have no citation, that Han was supposed to be talking rubbish there, hoping to fool these backwater rubes with technobabble. But nobody picked up on it, and made fun of Han/Lucas for bad a script.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Using 360 sub-units isn't necessarily Earth-centric. That comes directly from base-12 counting systems which are useful since 12 has a lot of divisors for a small number. 360 has loads of divisors so is pretty useful for partitioning things. This would also be true a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...

Comment: @RichardWard Well, according to _Solo_ he actually did the Kessel Run, which is usually 20 parsecs (IIRC) in almost 13 by taking a dangerous shortcut (and he rounds down because it sounds more impressive).

Comment: @DonielF I went and found [a script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html) (though I don't know how reliable the site is). After the "twelve parsecs" line, it says "Ben reacts to Solo's stupid attempt to impress them with obvious misinformation". Assuming the site is reliable, the claim was originally supposed to be hokum, but was retconned to be true.

Comment: @RichardWard I'm not sure this site is entirely accurate - I've usually seen good scripts from here, but they are ultimately submitted by users and the site does not publish its vetting guidelines. Also, this script appears to be from before [editing](https://www.polygon.com/2017/12/29/16829502/star-wars-wreck-editing) - while Han does shoot first, it also has many scenes that were cut in that edit, such as Luke hanging out at Tashi Station and Han's conversation with Jabba.

Comment: The most natural way to parse Han's line is to imagine "parsec" as a unit of time, not distance (as those of us more scientifically literate know it). I think it's a pretty safe bet that the scriptwriter(s) would have expected most of their 1977 audience to not know that "parsec" is a real word with a real meaning other than that which more naturally flows from the line in the script.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Parsecs, along with most other measurements of space and time in Star Wars most likely derive from Coruscant, the cradle of human civilisation and earliest explorers of the Galaxy.

The orbital period of Coruscant is 128-155 million miles, a fast elliptical orbit of roughly 1.3 - 1.6AU (as compared to Earth's 93 million miles - 1AU).

> CORUSCANT
>
> Coruscant orbits relatively far from its small sun, varying from 207 million to 251 million km (128 million to 155 million miles)
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Complete Locations (2016)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Locations)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know, Updated and Expanded](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know,_Updated_and_Expanded)</sup></sub>

That being the case, and given that we know that Coruscant's rotational period is 24 hours (giving us the concept of seconds of arc), one **PAR**allex **SEC**ond of arc would be a simple matter of calculation and would be similar to an Earth [parsec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec), albeit not identical, probably about 30% larger.

Obviously this presents a canon discontinuity, but not a large one, and easily explained by a writing error in the Complete Locations book. If we assume they meant 155 million *kilometers* (instead of miles), this distances would be only a few percent difference from the distance from the Earth to the Sun and would give us a parallax calculation that was almost identical.

Comment: Equal orbital period is not sufficient for a distance of 1AU; your assumption of 1AU holds only if the mass of Coruscant's sun is also equal to the mass of our own Sun.

Comment: (After your edit:) So, the actual answer seems to be that a Star Wars parsec is equal to 1.45 times our parsec; the "similar" part is arguably redundant...

Comment: @desertnaut - Ah, well my new line of thinking is that it's all messed up. A SW parsec seems to be the same as an Earth parsec, but the AU of Coruscant is wrong to do that measurement. Even though pretty much all measurements in Star Wars come from Coruscant. Either they've measured something else or the writers have just fouled up

Comment: Not sure I'm following (and your answer gives no indication of a "messed up" situation). How can that be, if the definition of parsec stays the same?

Comment: @desertnaut - If Coruscant orbits its star at 1.4AU, their parsec should be 40% larger. But it's not

Comment: 1) how do we know it's not (it's not that we have known waypoints to compare their distance)? 2) if it has nothing to do with the Coruscant's distance from its sun (as you seem to imply here), why including that part in your answer?

Comment: @desertnaut - It's worthy of mention because all distances and times in Star Wars derive from Coruscanti measurements.

Comment: If you think it's all "messed up", and SW parsec is identical with ours, fine, but your answer, as is, does **not** reflect this, and says something different (save for a speculation about a possible error); "*That being the case, and given that [...]*" does *not* lead to the conclusion that it is *similar albeit not identical* - it leads to 1.45 X

Comment: @desertnaut - I've reflected that in an edit. If they reversed the distances, their parsec would be only 3-4% different from ours. That seems too close to be a coincidence.

Comment: For an elliptical orbit like Coruscant's, the parallactic arcs for the same distance could be different depending on the direction we look at (and for some directions, also depending on when it was measured). This would mean the length of a parsec is not really constant.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - That is also true of Earth, which also has an elliptical orbit (albeit not as pronounced).

Answer (score 19):

They also use hours to measure time, which are just as Earth-centric. But remember, they don’t actually speak English in a galaxy far far away. Every word that is spoken on screen has been translated from the original language, so presumably the units have been translated into our units as well.

Comment: Hours aren't directly determined by our local astronomy; the hour is an *artificial* length of time into which some cultures of humans decided to divide the *natural* length of time we call a day. That said, I agree with your answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - In-universe, an hour is a 24th of the rotational period of Coruscant

Comment: @mikescott but why use parsec and not simply light year? That is a universal constant? Or now that it is a big franchise define parsec as the average distance between the sun and Coruscant but I am not able to find any such definition.

Comment: @Shade A light year isn’t a universal constant because a year isn’t a universal constant. It’s just as dependent on the exact details of the Earth‘s orbit around the sun as the AU and thus the parsec.

Comment: @Shade Here's one _possible_, purely speculative explanation: in Galactic Basic, there's a unit commonly used by pilots, travelers, and space enthusiasts when talking about intragalactic astronomical distances, but it's not used very often by anyone else. That means the word for that unit carries a connotation of being a little bit technical. Parsec fills a similar role in English - everyone says "light year" but you're more likely to hear "parsec" from astronomers and, well, scifi fans - so one might argue the translator of the script chose to use "parsec" to keep that impression.

Comment: @MikeScott The light-year has a precise definition which involves a "year" that is roughly equivalent to a calendar year. The IAU defines it as *exactly* 9 460 730 472 580 800 meters.

Comment: @chepner Yes, but the people of the galaxy far far away have no reason to use that distance as a unit of measurement — it has no meaning to them.

Comment: @chepner: Note also that the meter is defined as exactly 1 / 299,792,458 of a lightsecond, which is defined by the second, which is defined as 9,192,631,770 ticks of a Caesium-133 atom, which is used because it's approximately 1 / 86400 of a solar day on Earth.

Comment: @MichaelS Yes, but as you've already stated, "parsec" is just a *language* translation of whatever unit they are using, not a unit conversion. There's no reason to be leave their *y'adsr* (or whatever made-up alien word is being translated) is in one-to-one correspondence with "parsec". Otherwise, the *Millenium Falcon* would be the ship that made the Kessel Run in under 11.1834723493238 parsecs.

Comment: @chepner: I guess the concern here is how a light year could be a universal constant while a parsec is not (in reference to Shade's comment). Both are based on Earth orbital data, both have exact definitions that approximate said orbital data, both could have been "translated" from the "real" units used in the Star Wars universe, and neither parsecs nor light years were explicitly defined this way until long after the original movie was released. (A parsec is exactly 96,939,420,213,600,000 ÷ π meters by 2015 IAU definition.)

Comment: @MikeScott - A light year is the amount of distance light travels in one Coruscanti year

Comment: @Valorum So a parsec is the length at which the distance from Coruscant to its sun subtends one arcsecond. If a light year can be defined in terms of Coruscant then so can a parsec.

Answer (score 5):

#### Legends answer*: Parsecs aren't parallax-seconds, but are (somehow) the same length as real-world parsecs

In the Legends continuity, Coruscant's year (and by extension a standard year) is **368** 24-hour days long, not 365. *Star Wars: The Essential Atlas* (2009) mentions this, as well as confirming that Star Wars parsecs are 3.26 light-years long, the same as Earth parsecs.

I noticed that this seemed like a discrepancy, since a light-year with a longer year would be a different length than real-world light years (even assuming Coruscant otherwise had the same orbit as Earth for the purposes of parallax), so I emailed Daniel Wallace, the author of *The Essential Atlas*, in order to ask which values were being used. I asked whether A) in-universe light-years were longer than ours, B) Coruscant years were the same length as ours (and just had shorter days), or C) in-universe light-years and parsecs were the same length as ours and just arbitrarily defined.

Here is an excerpt from his reply, from 2009 (emphasis added):

> [...] I think our approach to units of timekeeping is to try to make them as equivalent to "real world" units of timekeeping as possible. This is both for the sake of our sanity and for the sake of making the universe something readers can relate to. So, while it's true that West End Games introduced a ten-month calendar, I personally will never use it, and Lucasfilm basically uses a 12-month calendar anyway.
>
> [...]
>
> Therefore, I'd be happiest if it turned out that Coruscant had a 24-hour rotation cycle and a 365-day orbital period, and an AU that is 149,597,870,691 meters. Turns out it doesn't, but we're still going to use real world references to avoid the need to make conversion calculations every time we provide a specific bit of data. If you think about it, the meter is one ten-millionth of the distance from Earth's equator to the North Pole, so technically the meter, kilometer, etc. don't have a basis in the GFFA but we keep using them anyway.
>
> You really hit on the problem when you reference the Decoded episode below. The writers of Decoded (and 99% of all novels, comics, and spinoff products) are going to use "real" figures because that's what they know -- **therefore the sane solution is to make all in-universe figures from the GFFA the same as ours.**
>
> From an in-universe perspective, I guess this makes it closest to your third solution, namely that **parsecs are either arbitrary or based on some other planet's measurements.** This is weird, I don't deny it -- but I think it does less damage to the SW universe than the alternative.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Dan

So, it looks like for the purposes of the authors of the Expanded Universe, the answer was closest to C): parsecs are the same as ours but not based on similar measurements. Now that an in-universe year is canonically 365 days, hopefully this is less of a headache for the authors.

*based on correspondence probably not authorized by Lucasfilm

Comment: Worthy of an upvote (for original research), even if the answer is unsatisfying.